# Selenium x-path get Radio button label text

Tags: xpath

Here is the HTML for 2 radio buttons and label text next to them. There are several radio buttons on the page, each with different shipping options. I am trying to verify that a specific option has the right price. So I need to get text from the tag AFTER the radio tag. So I am searching by the shipping option, but I need to get the text with the price:

```
<td valign="top">
<input type="radio" checked="" name="name" value="USPS Ground">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:name">
</td>
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px;" class="stdCopy">USPS Ground - $0.00<br>(All states: 4-9 business days. Delivery Monday&ndash;Saturday)
</td>
</tr>

<tr><td valign="top">
<input type="radio" name="name" value="USPS Priority*">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:name">
</td>
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px;" class="stdCopy">USPS Priority - $5.95<br>(All states: 3-5 business days. Delivery Monday-Saturday)
</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to use Selenium's `selenium.GetText(locator)`, but if my Selenium "locator" is @class="stdCopy", I will only get the first radio's text (USPS Ground). But I need to be able to access the right radio (given value=USPS Ground or value=USPS Priority) and verify the dollar amount - is it $0.00 or $5.95?

I need to define the locator with either XPATH or CSS statement (HOW?) to access the correct dollar amount in the right tag after the radio button.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium also supports Javascript selectors.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('stdCopy')[1]
```

(Btw.: I think that this also works, but I'm not sure:

```
@class="stdCopy"[1]
```

)

For the left radio, use `[0]` instead of `[1]`.